# XSLT transformation replacing occurenece of href elements by copying another element

Tags: xslt, href, fpml

I'm very new to XSLT transformation. 
I have to do a transformation of an FPML message into a simpler XML which will remove the href's and ID kind of attributes.(My target system doesn't understand this type of complex XML)

So part of my input XML is something like this

```
<fpml:partyTradeInformation>
               <fpml:partyReference href="Party1"/>
               <fpml:accountReference href="Book1"/>
</fpml:partyTradeInformation>

and in same xml at bottom is the Party1 reference
   <party id="Party1">
      <fpml:partyId partyIdScheme="urn:abc:party-id:EMX-LOH">What is the partyName for PQR?</fpml:partyId>
      <fpml:partyId partyIdScheme="urn:abc:party-id:PO_ID">PO19</fpml:partyId>
      <fpml:partyId partyIdScheme="urn:abc:party-id:PO">PO19</fpml:partyId>
      <fpml:partyId partyIdScheme="urn:abc:party-id:TREATS_ID">MNO</fpml:partyId>
      <fpml:partyName>What is the partyName for PQR?</fpml:partyName>
   </party>

Now first i have to transform my party1 to like below which I am able to do
   <Party1>
      <EMX-LOH>What is the partyName for ABC?</EMX-LOH>
      <PO_ID>PO19</PO_ID><PO>PO19</PO>
      <PO>PO19</PO>
      <TREATS_ID>XYZ</TREATS_ID>
      <partyName xmlns="">What is the partyName for ABC?</partyName>
   </Party1>

But then i have to also replace my  <fpml:partyReference href="Party1"/> like 
<partyReference>
   <party>
        <Party1>
          <EMX-LOH>What is the partyName for ABC?</EMX-LOH>
          <PO_ID>PO19</PO_ID><PO>PO19</PO>
          <PO>PO19</PO>
          <TREATS_ID>XYZ</TREATS_ID>
          <partyName xmlns="">What is the partyName for ABC?</partyName>
      </Party1>
   </party>
</partyReference >
```

How do i copy the transformed Party1 set of element at the href instance?
Also when i try to do a template match for Party1 which is the XSLT transformed element, the parser is not able to recognize it. But when i match the element party (which is the original one) the parser is able to recognize it.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please post a [mcve], including XML, your current XSLT and the expected output. -- I *think* you want to learn how to use a [key](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a start for an XSLT that will replace the party href with the corresponding party element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:fpml="http://www.example.com">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="fpml:partyReference[@href]">
        <xsl:variable name="href" select="@href" />
        <partyReference>
            <party>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//party[@id=$href]" mode="dereference" />
            </party>
        </partyReference>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="party" />

    <xsl:template match="party" mode="dereference">
        <xsl:element name="{@id}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*[not(local-name()='id')]" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Seeing how I don't know what your `fpml` prefix binds to, I put in some sample URI for that namespace.

The first template matching `node()|@*` is some standard approach that will just copy anything that doesn't match any other templates.

The second template matching `fpml:partyReference[@href]` will take any partyReference with a href attribute (in the given namespace), extract the value of @href to a variable, and then applies templates to any party element where the id attribute matches that href value. Notice how it introduces a mode named "dereference". That name is arbitrary and something I chose.

Next is an empty template that matches all `party` elements and does nothing. They won't get copied. This avoids copying the party again after it had already been placed in the reference earlier.

Finally is a template that matches all `party` elements, but only when in mode `dereference`. This will create a new element with as name the value of the `id` attribute and then applies templates to the attributes and child nodes, with the exception of the id attribute (since you don't want it copied in the output). This will just default to copying the contents.

Since I don't have enough information about what those `partyIdScheme` attributes in your input do, I haven't transformed those contents. The above should give you some indications of how to solve this. Note that you will need to alter the XSLT with the right namespace for prefix `fpml`, and that you may need to alter the namespace usage since your XML extracts leave some ambiguity about what is in which namespace (we'd need to see well-formed XML document to figure that out rather than extracts).

> Also when i try to do a template match for Party1 which is the XSLT transformed element, the parser is not able to recognize it. But when i match the element party (which is the original one) the parser is able to recognize it.

That is because XSLT only works on the input document. It traverses the input, matches its parts to templates and executes the instructions in those templates. It's a declarative language. So the output being generated is not part of the input and won't affect it. You'd need multiple XSLT transformations for that.

It's possible that the XML you're provided makes use of some technologies such as XInclude or other referencing schemes. You may be able to get your desired results using parsers that support the right technology or some library that implements such referencing schemes, so before you continue using XSLT, see if there's something that already does what you're trying.

EDIT: an example matching multiple elements in the same amount of templates as above. Note that this will only work if the `id` attribute in the input XML is unique for every element that can get referenced by `href`. Otherwise the results might be incorrect.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" 
    xmlns:fpml="http://www.example.com">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="fpml:partyReference[@href]|fpml:accountReference[@href]|fpml:payerPartyReference[@href]">
        <xsl:variable name="href" select="@href" />
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//*[@id=$href]" mode="dereference" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="party|account|payerParty" />

    <xsl:template match="party|account|payerParty" mode="dereference">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
            <xsl:element name="{@id}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*[not(local-name()='id')]" />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thankuu so much. This is what i was looking for. The namespaces isn't required in target xml. So Thinking of removing from input itself.

Comment: @rashb If this is sufficient to solve the question, please consider accepting it as the answer by clicking the tick mark under the score. This indicates you consider it to be the correct answer which helps other users and provides some reputation. If a better answer should be posted at a later time, you can still change which one you accept.

Comment: @rashb Yes, that is most certainly possible. The only tricky part is to know what to put in the part `<xsl:apply-templates select="//party[@id=$href]" mode="dereference" />`. It would have to be the right element instead of only `party`. If however the href attributes are guaranteed to be unique, even across different types, you could just use this: `<xsl:apply-templates select="//*[@id=$href]" mode="dereference" />` and adjust the template with the dereference mode. That one could use something like `party|account|payerParty...` to make sure only those are considered, or a wildcard.

Comment: but how do i know that which is the current matched template. Like if i do a ore'd match of party|account|payerparty i would also need the current matched template as my parent node in transformation.

Comment: @rashb I've added an XSLT that will do what I believe you're asking for, at the end the the answer.

Comment: Yes that helps. Thanks a lot again @G_H